# Chat not working and firebug isn't helping

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Clearly I must be doing something wrong with firebug because when I went to inspect my code I could not see any errors on anything. I know my code is not perfect, mainly because its an ajax chat and there's no chat going on. Maybe I'm utilizing it wrong, but I checked "All", "errors" and "warnings" for my website page which is [here](http://www.entrilab.com/chatroom/) and I got nothing returned. I have just started using firebug as well as programming as a whole so Im sure I'm missing something. It would be very grateful for any tips or pointers on what I could do to be better.

Comment: Do you want to add your code to the question?

Comment: "Chat not working" is not describing your problem. Please tell us what is going wrong, and show us the code in question.

Comment: Please add a clear, concise, and answerable question.  I don't know what you've tried and what you think the problem is.  Post your code snippets, and what you're struggling with.  I'm not going to dig through an entire application looking for bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look on the network tab, and try to add a login, says your php script is missing:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.entrilab.com/chatroom/php/ajax.php?action=login"
```